# Breaks in printing long contents JAVA

Tags: java, output, println

I have written a small program that takes user input, n (int), and calculates every prime number up to n, using a loop in a loop. If the user inputs forexample 85023, it will be a very long series of numbers. How do i make the output break every 10th number? this would make the output alot more proffesional and neat to look at.

Relevant code:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
    int counter=0;

        for(num =i; num>=1; num--)
        {
            if(i%num==0)
            {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
        if (counter ==2)
        {
            // Append prime numbers to string
            primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
        }
    }
    // Print Number
    System.out.println("Primtallene fra 1 til " + n + " er: ");
    System.out.println(primeNumbers);
}
```

Comment: count how often you found a primenumber yet and include a `\n` after 10 occurences

Comment: `counter = counter + 1;` could be shortened to `counter += 1;`, which itself could be shortened to `counter++;` (or `++counter;` - it doesn't matter in this instance)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a separate counter which counts the number of prime numbers you have currently found, like this:

```
int primeCount = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
    int counter=0;

        for(num =i; num>=1; num--)
        {
            if(i%num==0)
            {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
        if (counter ==2)
        {
            // Append prime numbers to string
            primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
            // Increment prime counter
            primeCount++;
            // If 10 primes have been printed then add new line and reset counter
            if ((primeCount % 10) == 0) {
               primeNumbers += "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    // Print Number
    System.out.println("Primtallene fra 1 til " + n + " er: ");
    System.out.println(primeNumbers);
}
```

`\n` is the newline character, hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of "== 10", it should be ((primeCount % 10) = 0) (Which means "If it is divisible by 10), otherwise only one break will be added (following the first 10).

Comment: You could also do `if (primeCount % 10 == 0) {...}` so that you didn't need to reset `primeCount` each time

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't notice that. Although JonK has a good point, better to avoid making more complex code if you can.